# sqlite3_prepare fails if db opened with SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY

Tags: sqlite

sqlite3_prepare function fails if DB is opened with SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY.

```
Error message:  error #10: disk I/O error 
Sqlite extended error code: SQLITE_IOERR_LOCK (3850)
Errno: EBADF 9  /* Bad file number */
```

Everything works fine if DB is opened with SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | 
SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX;
Any ideas on what may cause this problem?

```
rc=sqlite3_open_v2("example.db",&db,SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY,0);
sqlite3_busy_timeout(db,1000); 
selectQuery = "select * from test;";
rc = sqlite3_prepare(db, selectQuery, strlen(selectQuery), &stmt, 0);
if(rc!=SQLITE_OK) 
{
    printf("sql error #%d: %s", rc, sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    printf( "SQL ext error: %d\n", sqlite3_extended_errcode(db));
    printf( "errno: %d\n", errno );
}
```

Comment: Does this DB use WAL? What file system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in OS lock implementation. Fcntl() doesn't allow to lock file if it is opened with read only permissions. As a result - SQLite can't do anything in read only mode.